# SQL Server case in where clause conditionally

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, conditional-statements, where-clause

```
select * 
from someTable 
where currencyid = @currencyid  --CaseA
   or (Currencyid in (8,11) or (@Currencyid = 0)) --CaseB
```

How to modify such query so that when `@currencyid = 0` the condition will be set on ONLY CaseB while others set as CaseA?

For example:
if `@currencyid = 0` then the end query to be executed is

```
select * 
from someTable 
where currencyid = (Currencyid in (8,11) or (@Currencyid = 0))
```

if `@currencyid = 8` then the end query to be executed is

```
select * 
from someTable 
where currencyid = @currencyid
```

Comment: Eh? You want a condition that says `@Currencyid = 0` to be applied, but only in circumstances where you know that `@CurrencyId` cannot be zero? How does that make sense?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : Sorry for causing confusion. I've updated the question thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM someTable
WHERE (currencyid = @Currencyid AND @Currencyid != 0)
    OR (Currencyid IN (8, 11) AND @Currencyid = 0)
--OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```